# Two different static libs with the same .obj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, object-files, .lib

I'm working with visual studio, 
and I have two different static libs which share the same .obj file, but that .obj file is newer in one of them.
I need both of these libs so i can't exclude one of them,
How can I "make" the linker to take this specific .obj file from the static lib I want him to?

Comment: 1: don't do that.  2: see 1.  3: see 1.  4: the order you pass the .lib files to the linker matters.

Answer (score 1):

It's either that or i will have to add the `.obj` file every time he has been changed, cause it's location is based on the version number while the lib file is in a global location.
Unless there's other solution.